# php incrementation not working sql

Tags: php, sql

When i use random function it is working it give me 3 random value , but when i use the variable who contain a number , the number stay the same ?

```
foreach ($list_of_codes as $k => $v)
{
    //  $rand = rand(1,15);
    $rand = $refidorder;
    $code = $rand++;
}
```

Comment: $rand++ is a post increment, so the value is used and then incremented.  Use ++$rand.

Comment: `$rand = $refidorder;` So what's `$refidorder`, and where is it changed inside your loop? If it isn't changed, then it will always have the same value that's being assigned to `$rand`, and to `$code`

Comment: You should use `$rand + 1`. It makes no sense to increment the variable if you're just going to reassign it the next time through the loop.

Comment: still not working its give me the same value

Comment: You need to clarify the question then. Show what you're expecting and what you're getting instead.

Comment: The code you've posted will always give the same value in $rand and in $code; there's  nothing to change it.... what is $refidorder?

Comment: $sql = 'SELECT id_order_detail FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'order_detail WHERE id_order = '.$params['id_order'].' AND product_id = '.$idproductoforder.'';
                         $refidorder = Db::getInstance()->getValue($sql);

Comment: this query return one id at time , i want to make a query for each id but cant make it ,